# kCGErrorFailure while performing drag and drop in NSView

Tags: cocoa, xcode, drag-and-drop, breakpoints, nsview

I have created a simple drag and drop application in which I am sometimes getting this exception msg, displayed in debugger console:

> kCGErrorRangeCheck:
>   CGSNewWindowWithOpaqueShape: Cannot
>   create window
>
> kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @
>   CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as
>   they are logged.
>
> kCGErrorIllegalArgument:
>   CGSMoveWindow: Invalid window 0x0
>
> kCGErrorIllegalArgument:
>   CGSOrderWindowList
>
> kCGErrorIllegalArgument:
>   CGSOrderWindowList
>
> kCGErrorIllegalArgument:
>   CGSGetWindowBounds: NULL window
>
> kCGErrorIllegalArgument:
>   CGSMoveWindow: Invalid window 0x0
>
> kCGErrorIllegalArgument:
>   CGSOrderWindowList
>
> kCGErrorIllegalArgument:
>   CGSGetWindowBounds: NULL window

Can anyone suggest me why is it occurring and how can I resolve it?

Also can anyone suggest how to set breakpoint for @CGErrorBreakpoint() so that I can debug and trace its cause?

The code in concludeDragOperation is:

```
NSPoint dropLocation = [sender draggedImageLocation];
id dragSource = [sender draggingSource];
NSPasteboard *pb = [sender draggingPasteboard];
NSData *draggedData = [pb dataForType:IconDragDataType];
id unarchievedObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:draggedData];
[unarchievedObject setFrameOrigin:dropLocation];
```

Thanks,

Miraaj

Comment: What class is unarchievedObject?

Comment: it is subclass of NSView, in its mouseDown: method I am initiating the drag operation

Answer (score 2):

To set a breakpoint in CGErrorBreakpoint open the breakpoints window (command-option-B), double-click on the line that says "Double-Click for Symbol" and enter CGErrorBreakpoint in the text field.